# conflicting server name "localhost" warning on nginx

Tags: nginx, https, localhost

I am trying to set up nginx for my localhost on a linux cntainer
Here is the config

```
## server configuration
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen 80 ;
    ## add ssl entries when https has been set in config
    ssl_certificate      /etc/ssl/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key  /etc/ssl/key.pem;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

    server_name localhost;
    if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = '') {
        set $http_x_forwarded_proto  $scheme;
    }
    ## Application specific logs
    ## access_log /var/log/nginx/localhost-access.log timing;
    ## error_log /var/log/nginx/localhost-error.log;
    rewrite ^/$ /artifactory/webapp/ redirect;
    rewrite ^/artifactory/?(/webapp)?$ /artifactory/webapp/ redirect;
    location /artifactory/ {
    proxy_read_timeout  900;
    proxy_pass_header   Server;
    proxy_cookie_path ~*^/.* /;
    proxy_pass         http://localhost:8081/artifactory/;
    proxy_set_header   X-Artifactory-Override-Base-Url $http_x_forwarded_proto://$host:$server_port/artifactory;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Port  $server_port;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto $http_x_forwarded_proto;
    proxy_set_header    Host              $http_host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}

## server configuration
server {
    listen 6555 ssl;


    server_name localhost;
    if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = '') {
        set $http_x_forwarded_proto  $scheme;
    }
    ## Application specific logs
    ## access_log /var/log/nginx/localhost-access.log timing;
    ## error_log /var/log/nginx/localhost-error.log;
    rewrite ^/(v1|v2)/(.*) /artifactory/api/docker/docker-virtual/$1/$2;
    client_max_body_size 0;
    chunked_transfer_encoding on;
    location /artifactory/ {
    proxy_read_timeout  900;
    proxy_pass_header   Server;
    proxy_cookie_path ~*^/.* /;
    proxy_pass         http://localhost:8081/artifactory/;
    proxy_set_header   X-Artifactory-Override-Base-Url $http_x_forwarded_proto://$host:$server_port/artifactory;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Port  $server_port;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto $http_x_forwarded_proto;
    proxy_set_header    Host              $http_host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

After I retsrat nginx I get the following error

```
nginx: [warn]nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "localhost" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
```

"localhost" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored

Also when I navigate to the browser I get a connection refused on localhost:443

What might be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

your server can't resolve your domain name `localhost` as one IP address

you may have a duplicate entry of your local virtual host name in `hosts` file

lines should be seen in `host` file

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
0.0.0.0 localhost
```

delete or modify second one

This problem could be caused also by running virtual DNS service like unbound

if you are running so, be sure to configure it correctly